# Trying to create an executable using py2exe however 'run.py' will not run

Tags: python, py2exe

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJAM8_Lx5mY&ab_channel=CodersLegacy

When run the 'run.py' file nothing happens. Its suppose to open a GUI

Comment: Ahh interesting. I wonder what your code looks like to produce such a behavior?

Comment: In the tutorial, download auto-py-exe from github. I run the specified file then nothing happens

Comment: You'll find that overwhelming majority of people here are not going to parse a youtube video for a specific github link and then download the code to run it for an ill formed low effort question of a random person online. Especially when that person could literally copy past the code into the question and provide meaningful background themselves. If you show no effort, don't expect others to.